# iOS. 12h/24h time format in iOS 6 and 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, time, format

As I understand in iOS 6 only one option defines time format - "24 hour format" switch.

But in iOS 7 device additionally can change 12h/24h time format according to a selected "region".

Should I track this iOS 7 behaviour separately?

Currently I use the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSRange amRange = [dateString rangeOfString:[formatter AMSymbol]];
NSRange pmRange = [dateString rangeOfString:[formatter PMSymbol]];
BOOL is24h = (amRange.location == NSNotFound && pmRange.location == NSNotFound);
[formatter release];
NSLog(@"%@\n",(is24h ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
```